# SQL functions in NetSuite saved search results - how to fix these functions?

Tags: sql, netsuite

I am trying to achieve the following in the context of NetSuite saved search results output.

**1. Remove every character after the first hyphen (-) or a colon (:) including space right before either of these characters.**

So for e.g.

Input: **test 123 - xyz : 123**

this should output as **test 123** -> this should even remove the space that you see right before the hyphen.

I tried the below two codes

`SUBSTR({custitem123}, 0, INSTR({custitem123}, '-')-1)
SUBSTR({custitem123}, 0, INSTR({custitem123}, ':')-1)`

And these work fine on their own- so I am trying to combine these in one single formula that will look for either of these and remove all characters after them -- apart from this, it should also look for any space right before the hyphen or colon and replace it with nothing. Not sure how you would achieve this.

**2. Remove all non-alphabet characters & space before the alphabet characters (if any).**

for e.g.  Input:   **1. Test XYZ**

This should have Output as:
**Test XYZ**

I tried achieving this by using the below formula-

`TRIM({class}, '[^A-Za-z ]', '')`

The problem with this approach is it fails to replace the space character before the first alphabet of Test. I understand this is because I told it to skip replacing space characters. What I don't know is how do I tell it to **only replace** the space that it finds before the *first* alphabet character.

In short, how do I make sure the output is:
**Test XYZ**

And not

Test XYZ  (that has a space before Test)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_substr` as

`regexp_substr({custitem123}, '[^-]+')` to extract `test 123` only from Input: `test 123 - xyz : 123`

if you add `trim` also, then you can get whitespaces around trimmed as

e.g. `trim(regexp_substr({custitem123}, '[^-]+'))` gives `test 123` as trimmed output.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly almost - I used it as follows: `regexp_substr({custitem123}, '[^-:]+')`  Only thing it does not do is it doesn't remove the space character which is left as the last character - so it extracts `test 123 ` instead of `test 123`

Answer (score 0):

use RTRIM instead of Trim to remove the trailing whitespaces like this:

`RTRIM(regexp_substr({custitem123}, '[^-]+'))`

test 123 - xyz : 123 resolves to test 123

Also thanks for asking this question helped me solve my own similar issue :D